# What Software Do You Use To Create Sitemaps / Site Structure For Large Sites?

Tags: sitemap, web

Just wondering what software you use to create a visual sitemap / site structure representation before you start big sites?

I am looking to map out a large site, but cannot find any good software to help me map the site visually (And in pages/categories)..

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest taking a look at this tool:  http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups

The **Balsamiq** tool is the best for doing mockups (i assume this is what you are referring too when talking about sitemaps before you start...).  With this software you can quickly generate a working wireframe of what ever you are creating.  So much functionality that you can actually share it with your client to get some good sign offs prior to typing the first bit of code.

Very powerful!

And the other one...just shown at the last MIX09 is **SketchFlow**.  Couldn't remember it to save my life.  This is a WAY COOL tool for site maps and UI mock up.  I was trying to find you the actual MIX presentation as it is super cool to watch.  But here are some YouTube videos of that presentation from a user perspective I guess.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zsAZjb7FKXA

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f3ErrS68YMM

Check it out!

**update**...found the SketchFlow video!!!  http://videos.visitmix.com/MIX09/C01F

Great keynote from there too: http://videos.visitmix.com/MIX09/KEY01

Comment: Sorry I think I didn't explain myself enough - When I mean sitemap I mean actual map of the site... Like a mindmap/brain storm?  Working out navigation structure, categories etc...

Comment: Yes...for that you want to use SketchFlow.  You can actually design a sitemap that works in real time.  Watch the SketchFlow video for an idea of what this entails...as it is super easy.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe SketchFlow http://electricbeach.org/?p=145 ? which is included in the Expression Blend Trial http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=92E1DB7A-5D36-449B-8C6B-D25F078F3609&displaylang=en

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but for others who find this via search, I personally love mocking my websites up with mind mapping tools. I've tried several but my favorite was MindNode for Mac and Xmind for Windows.

XMind free download:
http://www.xmind.net/

MindNode free download:
https://mindnode.com/

I've also tried MindMeister which works just as well as other mind mapping tools and is hosted for you so you can access your mind maps anywhere. However, MindMeister only allows you three maps (currently) without upgrading to a paid subscription.

Another that I've worked with is mockflow.com which is great for mocking up websites with all their features and buttons and even making clickable navigation. They have a free version, but again it's very limited without upgrading to a paid version.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Slickplan. This cloud based app allows me to have access to my projects from different machines regardless of their operating systems. All I need is one of the leading web browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Safari).

With Slickplan you can create visual sitemaps from scratch or you can use Site Crawler to import your existing website to visualize and reorganize its structure.

Of course you can always export your projects to the XML format, and use the exported file to create pages and menu systems inside some popular content management system - Slickplan provides plugins for WordPress, Joomla, concrete5 and a few more.